# Makefile: Use output of one command as argument to other

Tags: makefile, io-redirection

As a part of the build process, Make creates several `.tgz` files:

```
blah_1.tgz blah_2.tgz .... blah_n.tgz
```

How do I invoke another command (e.g., `rsync`) on each file?

In bash, I would:

```
for file in `ls *.tgz`' do rsync $file DESTINATION; done
```

Or:

```
ls | grep tgz | xargs rsync {} DESTINATION
```

But the familiar bash syntax doesn't seem to comply with Make. Any ideas?

Comment: `rsync` allows multiple sources so you should just be able to do `rsync *.tgz DESTINATION`

Comment: +1 thanks, but `rsync` is just an example here, for clarity. The actual executable takes only one file as argument.

Comment: OK - does the actual executable produce any output file(s) when you pass it a .tgz file as input ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm... Something like this should work:

```
TGZ_FILES := blah_1.tgz blah_2.tgz .... blah_n.tgz
RSYNC_TARGETS := $(TGZ_FILES:%=rsync-%)

all : $(RSYNC_TARGETS)

.PHONY : $(RSYNC_TARGETS)
$(RSYNC_TARGETS) : rsync-% : %
    rsync $* DESTINATION

# Omit the following rule
# if .tgz files are made somewhere else (outside Make),
# and you assume they are always up-to-date
$(TGZ_FILES) : %.tgz : ...
    # rule to make each .tgz file
```

This example uses the following features of GNU Make:

- [Substitution References](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Substitution-Refs) (`$(TGZ_FILES:%=rsync-%)`)
- [Static Pattern Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern) (`$(RSYNC_TARGETS) : rsync-% : %`)
- [Phony Targets](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets) (`.PHONY : $(RSYNC_TARGETS)`)
- [Automatic Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) (`$*`)

Comment: The `.tgz` files don't exist prior to the Makefile execution, so they can't be listed at the top of the file.

Comment: @Adam then you can extract this code into a separate makefile, say, `rsync.mk` and invoke it in a sub-make: `$(MAKE) -f rsync.mk TGZ_FILES='...'`.